# Ruby; Can a string be parsed so that `2016-12-01` is a day, and `2016-12-01T12:05` is a minute?

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime

*Using vanilla Ruby (or Rails, but prefer vanilla Ruby),*

Supposing custom classes are created by us: `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minute`, `Second`, `Millisecond`
With these classes, they relate to a specific hour, minute, second, etc.

Example: `thisMinute = Minute.new("2016-12-01T12:05") => Minute 5 of hour 12 of day 1 of month 12 of year 2016`

#### Can a function be created so that

`foo("2016")` can create an instance of the `Year` Class

`foo("2016/12")` can create an instance of the `Month` Class

`foo("2016-12-01")` can create an instance of the `Day` Class

`foo("2016-12-01T12:05")` can create an instance of the `Minute` Class

and so-on?

#### Here are the gotchas

- The time format may vary (`"20161201"` or `"20161201@12pm"` for example)
- With these formats, `Time.parse` will successfully parse the string, but will set `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, etc so that `"20161201"` would have a value set for Hour, even though it should be a `Day`.
- Checking for `== 0` (as in `Time.parse().hour == 0`) would fail as the time could be `"2016-12-01@12am"`

Comment: What `Minute` class are you talking about? Is this something you've constructed?

Comment: You certainly could do that, but it's hard to imagine what problem it would solve. Can you tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @tadman - Yes, something we've constructed

Comment: @Jordan - It's a bit complicated to explain in a comment, but we have a UTC timetree in a graph database, and events connect to nodes on the tree. The unique 'key' is the name of the node (String): `(20161201_12)-[:ZOOM_OUT]->(20161201)`. Event nodes are added to the tree like `(event)-[:OCCURRED_AT]->(20161201)`. An event can occur at any level (For example, not knowing what time something happened, only the day), so an event that occurred on a day can't be connected to the Second `20161201_000000`, but should be connected to the Day node.

Comment: I played around with a time implementation like this. Check it out: https://github.com/silverhammermba/chrono

Comment: You're going to have to do some work here to integrate the ideas people have given you and come up with a solution. You don't really have a lot of sample data here, it's just hints. It's not even clear what `Minute` is or how it would be populated.

Comment: What is it that motivates you to create classes for each component of the date/time? Is it really worth the cost of the added complexity?

Comment: @KeithBennett The biggest reason is that it allows them to have a distinct hierarchy, which allows things like "connect this second to the time tree root" that practically instantly connects the second to it's minute, hour, day, month, year, and decade while creating uncreated nodes along the way.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way would be to have a parse method for each class.  stftime is used to pull specific parts of a time stamp out

```
a = '2016-12-01T12:05'
=> "2016-12-01T12:05"
b = DateTime.parse(a)
=> #<DateTime: 2016-12-01T12:05:00+00:00 ((2457724j,43500s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
b.strftime("%M") # minute
=> "05"
b.strftime("%H") # hour
=> "12"
b.strftime("%d") # day of month
=> "01"
b.strftime("%m") # month
=> "12"
```

So each class would use a different stfrtime() param to filter down to what ever part of the time stamp you need.

http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while these work, `b.minute`, `b.day` and so forth is probably more concise.

Comment: Definitely.  If you can use the `.minute`, `.hour`, etc... use them.  strftime will give you more customizable combinations of a time stamp when those don't meet your needs.  ex -> `b.strftime("%d, %H:%M") => "01, 12:05"`

Comment: Oh, for sure, both options are valid depending on your requirements. Just don't do `b.strftime('%M').to_i`.

Comment: I think this might work, but it's only half the solution. Do you have a solution for figuring out which Class to parse with?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the half is.  I would parse the minutes in a minute class taking your example of Minute.new above

Comment: comments are hard to leave code in.  But if you want to call Minute.new(time) and have that string your wrote in your question be returned.  I would have the initialize method of Minute take a string of time, then parse that time with DateTime.parse() and set that to an instance var.  From there call another method to pull out the min, hour, day, year and set them all to vars.  Then put the variables into a string (ex -> "Minute #{min} of hour #{hour} ...") and puts thats string( if this is just going to be run through console) at the end

Comment: The other half is: Say there's only `setDate (string)`, how will the function know to instantiate a Day, Month, Minute, etc? `string.length` won't work for example because the string could have `/`, `-` or other characters.

Comment: Thanks to your probing, I realized that the question could be worded better by asking about the function we want to create. Having noticed that, I realize why people were misunderstanding.